# set Ant build path

Tags: gwt, ant

I am using ant for build gwt app.

following code is ant config. I want that the built files(nocache.js etc) is be placed to C:\WebServers\home\tcl.lc\www\

now it builds to war wolder.

```
<project name="MyProject" default="gwtc" basedir=".">

<property name="build.dir"  value="C:\WebServers\home\tcl.lc\www\"/>
<property name="src.dir" value="src"/>

<path id="compile.classpath">
    <fileset dir="C:\gwt-2.2.0" includes="*.jar"/>
</path>

<target name="hosted" description="Starts gwt project in a standalone hosted browser and runs embedded jetty on port 8888">
    <java failonerror="true" fork="true" classname="com.google.gwt.dev.HostedMode">
        <classpath>
            <pathelement location="${src.dir}"/>
            <path refid="compile.classpath"/>
        </classpath>
        <jvmarg value="-Xms256M"/>
        <jvmarg value="-Xmx256M"/>
        <arg value="-startupUrl"/>
        <arg value="index.html"/>
        <arg value="com.typingApplication.TypingApplication"/>
    </java>
</target>

<target name="gwtc" description="GWT compile to JavaScript">
    <java failonerror="true" fork="true" classname="com.google.gwt.dev.Compiler">
        <classpath>
            <pathelement location="${src.dir}"/>
            <path refid="compile.classpath"/>
        </classpath>
        <jvmarg value="-Xmx256M"/>
        <arg value="com.typingApplication.TypingApplication"/>
    </java>
</target>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideCompilingAndDebugging.html#DevGuideCompilerOptions (and http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideCompilingAndDebugging.html#What_options_can_be_passed_to_development_mode for the DevMode)

in short, add these to your targets' java tasks:

```xml
<arg value="-war" />
<arg value="${build.dir}" />
```

Comment: if add it in java task compiler class get it as module name not path then gives Invalida module name :(

Comment: As the doc says, the module name(s) has to be the last argument(s), so place the "-war ${build.dir}" before it (just after your <jvmarg/>s will be fine)

Comment: Thanks Broyer. It worked, I just forgot to write about that. sorry